# Improve SQL CTE query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, common-table-expression

Is there any way to improve the performance of the following CTE query (`@E` and `@R` are tables with indexes in the actual system):

```
DECLARE @id bigint = 1

DECLARE @E TABLE
(
id bigint,
name varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @R TABLE
(
child_id bigint,
parent_id bigint
)

INSERT INTO @E SELECT 1, 'one'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 2, 'two'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 3, 'three'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 4, 'four'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 5, 'five'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 6, 'six'
INSERT INTO @E SELECT 7, 'seven'

INSERT INTO @R SELECT 1, 2
INSERT INTO @R SELECT 1, 3
INSERT INTO @R SELECT 3, 4
INSERT INTO @R SELECT 5, 4
INSERT INTO @R SELECT 3, 6
INSERT INTO @R SELECT 7, 4

; WITH cte
(
child_id,
parent_id
)

AS (

SELECT * FROM @R R
WHERE R.child_id = @id

UNION ALL
SELECT R.* FROM @R R
INNER JOIN cte ON CTE.parent_id = R.child_id

)
SELECT * FROM @E E
WHERE e.id = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT P.* FROM @E E
INNER JOIN cte ON 1=1
INNER JOIN @E P ON P.id = cte.parent_id
WHERE e.id = @id
ORDER BY 1
```

Expected Results:

```
id | name
1  | one 
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
6  | six
```

In real world data I will be dealing with many millions of rows in @R and about a hundred thousand rows in in @E. So I'm looking to see if there's anything I can do to squeeze a little more performance out.

Edit: just to clarify and summarize so far, there is a clustered pk index on R with `child_id, parent_id` and adding an index to `@r.parent_id` will also improve join performance.

Is there anything improve this? The bit after the CTE with the `inner join 1=1` is there anything that could be improved upon here is is that about as good as it will get? Is there any other schema design I could do to get similar parent-child mapping with better performance?

Comment: Make sure any column that's used for joining is indexed, e.g. `child_id` and `parent_id` and so on - this would improve JOIN performance

Comment: Do you know how many levels of parent-child relationships you are likely to have in your real-world data?

Comment: @marc_s there will be a clustered index on [child_id, parent_id] for this table.

Comment: @MarkBannister: real world data is likely to only go down to around 10 levels, say 20 at the most but there's no direct limit.

Comment: @Seph: that's not good enough - you should have separate indices on both `(child_id)` and `(parent_id)` to speed up JOIN performance. If you have a compound index on `(child_id, parent_id)` in that order, then this can be used for `child_id` alone - but not for `parent_id` alone (and it will need both)

Comment: @marc_s true, I completely missed that, I wasn't sure how CTE behaves with indexes when running recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As marc_s pointed out

a clustered index on `[child_id, parent_id]` for this table is not good enough - you should have separate indices on both `(child_id)` and `(parent_id)` to speed up JOIN performance. If you have a compound index on `(child_id, parent_id)` in that order, then this can be used for `child_id` alone - but not for `parent_id` alone (and it will need both) – marc_s Dec 19 '11 at 12:35

This greatly improved the performance of the query and helped me understand how CTE queries work internally.

Answer (score 0):

For the very beginning:

```
DECLARE @E TABLE
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @R TABLE
(
    child_id bigint,
    parent_id BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY(child_id, parent_id),
    UNIQUE (parent_id, child_id)
)
```

But, keep in mind that Sql Server is very poor in optimizing CTEs.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for `SQL Server is very poor in optimizing CTEs`?  It's not my personal experience...

Comment: So, I'll be a little bit more polite - SOMETIMES SQL Server is very poor in optimizing CTEs. 8-) If you want the proper evidences - I'll try to figure it out, but I already bumped into this behavior some times.

Comment: Remembered the issues - if you use ranking functions - ROW_NUMBER(), for example, inside the CTE - the CTE becomes paifully slow

Comment: @Oleg: And you are sure it is not because you used ROW_NUMBER() with ordering by non-indexed columns, aren't you?